# Calculating previous date in batch file is borked

Tags: batch-file

There are tons of questions on here about calculating with variables in batches and they are pretty helpful but I haven't found one for this specific problem.  What I'm trying to do is have a user input a date in MM-DD format for a batch task they have to do periodically.  Crucially here is that it pulls files from the day BEFORE the selected date from SQL tables.  Pulling from SQL is no problem, but I am running into an issue calculating the previous date.  The snippet of code below is simplified to demonstrate the problem I'm having, using "ECHO" rather than "BCP" just for the purpose of illustration.

```
SET /P DA=Input a two digit day: 
IF %DA% GEQ 2 SET /A Dmin=DA-1
IF %DA% LEQ 10 SET Dmin=0%Dmin%
ECHO You Input %DA%
ECHO Calc got %Dmin%
```

I need the two digit format because the date portion of the SQL command is formatted MM-DD-YYYY
The problem here is that if you enter a date of 02 through 07 it outputs 01 through 06 as expected, and it behaves for values of 10+ as well.  But if the user inputs "08" or "09" it outputs just "0" or nothing at all (Or whatever the last variable was prior to the 08 or 09, adding more 0's as you go.

Why does it do this?  What is special about 08 and 09 that causes this strange behavior and how can I fix that?

Comment: If you've used/are using a similar method for month input, what happens when the end user inputs `03` for `mm` and `01` for `DD`. For this reason alone, I would advise that you use a programming tool with support for dates as objects instead. The next thing I'd advise is that you ensure that the input matches the format and range of possible entries, before trying to use it for the purpose intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some things to keep in mind when building this type of function.

- Input Validation : test and restrict user input to appropriate numeric ranges
- Removal of leading zero's. Calculations you'll need to do will fail if you attempt to perform them with values that contain Leading Zero's
- Conversion of variables to an equal form for comparison.

  - Use substring modification to extract information and order it prior to performing converting calculations on the data - this of course requires you to know what format the data is in initially to decide what modifications need to be made on it.

When it comes to validating input for a specific numeric range, a method like this can be used:

```
@Echo Off
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    :MM
    Set /p "MM=Enter Numeric value for MM:"
    For /L %%A in (1,1,12) Do (If "%%A"=="!MM!" Goto :DD)
    Goto :MM
    :DD
    Set /p "DD=Enter Numeric value for DD:"
    For /L %%A in (1,1,31) Do (If "%%A"=="!DD!" Goto :YYYY)
    Goto :DD
    :YYYY
    Set /p "YYYY=Enter Numeric value for YYYY:"
    For /L %%A in (1985,1,2100) Do (If "%%A"=="!YYYY!" Goto :Next)
    Goto :YYYY
    :Next
    REM Your Commands Here
    pause
```

A methodology for removing leading zero's from a variable is:

`Set /A var = 100%var% %% 100`

A function to convert dates to julian date for use in comparisons - particularly in older than / by X day scenario's:

```
:ConvertJulian <DD> <MM> <YYYY> <resultVar>

REM DD and MM values MUST have leading zero's removed prior to being passed to this function as parameters

    Setlocal
    Set "Day=%1"
    Set "Month=%2"
    Set /a "MonthCv=( %Month% - 14 ) / 12"
    Set /a "YearCv=%3 + 4800"
    Set /a "Julian=1461 * ( %YearCv% + %MonthCv% ) / 4 + 367 * ( %Month% - 2 -12 * %MonthCv% ) / 12 - ( 3 * ( ( %YearCv% + %MonthCv% + 100 ) / 100 ) ) / 4 + %Day% - 32075"

    (
    Endlocal
    Set "%4=%Julian%"
    exit /b
    )
```

See [here](https://pastebin.com/F4yUs8Bq) or for a practical example

Comment: I do have validation in the script earlier on, the actual user input does a few things and I am restricted in two key ways, I must use a batch and and the final output MUST have two digits, meaning for dates below 10 there must be a leading 0.  This is because the user is being prompted to generate a list of dates for which The final use of this information is in three ways.  A list of dates selected in MM-DD-YYYY, a list of dates selected minus one day, and a third party application that only accepts dates formatted as YYMMDD.  Not having the leading 0 on single digit days is not an option.

Comment: I'm still stuck with the current values, leading zeroes included, working for days 01 through 07 but not 08 and 09.  Why are those two days different?  From your answers it shouldn't work for 01-07 either.

Comment: In that Situation, Leading Zero's can be retained in the Variable and removed within the local environment of Subroutines that Process the Date Information.

Comment: Alternately, you can use a secondary variable for the times you wish to append a zero in DDMMYY By using the Following: `If "!Var:~,-1!"=="" (Set "VarCopy=0!Var!")`

Comment: The above will insert a zero at the start of the variable in the event the Variable is a single digit

Comment: I got it working thanks to your answer... I really appreciate that. The key was that stripping the leading 0 for the math, then adding it back in for values less than 10 in the output.  Works perfectly.  Thank you very much.

Comment: No worries. As for why this Behaviour occurs with leading zero's, read the sections here: `https://ss64.com/nt/set.html` regarding Octal Numbers